# Should the tags 'pivottable' and 'pivot-table' be merged and aliassed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

There are two rather closely related tags, currently both present on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963396/pivot-table-query-from-sql-tables-gives-error-sometimes):

- [pivot-table](/questions/tagged/pivot-table) with over 100 questions so tagged.
- [pivottable](/questions/tagged/pivottable) with just over 20 questions so tagged.

It seems to me that the hyphen-less tag should be merged with the hyphenated tag and the hyphen-less tag should be made into a synonym for the hyphenated tag.

Any comments or objections?

Comment: Sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've manually updated the [pivottable](/questions/tagged/pivottable) tags to [pivot-table](/questions/tagged/pivot-table) (or, in the fairly frequent cases where the question had both tags, deleted the [pivottable](/questions/tagged/pivottable) tag).

I'm not able to vote to create the synonym - not enough points earned.  And I'm not exactly sure what to put into the Wiki, so I have added nothing for [pivot-table](/questions/tagged/pivot-table).  I have proposed a message "This tag should not be used; use the tag [pivot-table](/questions/tagged/pivot-table) instead" for the [pivottable](/questions/tagged/pivottable) tag.